# jQuery: create html elements from comma separated string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create HTML elements (div's) from a comma separated string using jQuery.

Lets say I have a string that looks like this:

```
options ="some texts, another text, some more text";
```

and I need to create something like this:

```
<div>some texts</div>
<div>another text</div>
<div>some more text</div>
```

I first split the comma separated string like so:

```
var str = options;
var temp = new Array();
temp = str.split(", ");
```

And then I need to create the div's after this function which I have no idea how to do this.

Could someone please advise on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var options ="some texts, another text, some more text";
var temp = options.split(", "); // first split string and convert it to array
var str = '';
$.each(temp, function(i,v) { // loop through array
  str += "<div>"+v+"</div>"; // create html string and store it in str variable
});
$("body").append(str);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this using jQuery

```js
var options = "some texts, another text, some more text";
var temp = options.split(", ");

// iterate and generate array of jQuery elements
var divs = temp.map(function(txt) {
  // generate div using jQuery with text content as array element
  return $('<div/>', {
    text: txt
  })
})

// update html content, use `append()` if you want to append instead of replacing entire content
$('body').html(divs);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to convert to an array- just replace the commas and associated spaces with a closing div and opening div tag and then add an opening one to start with and a closing one to end with and you have the html structure.

```
var options ="some texts, another text, some more text";
var temp = "<div>" + options.replace(/, /g,"</div><div>") + "</div>; 
   //this will give: <div>some texts</div><div>another text</div><div>some more text</div>

$("body").append(temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the text interpreted as **text**, not HTML, you'll want to loop over the array your code gives you and create elements individually, like this:

```js
var options = "some texts, <another> text, some more text";
options.split(", ").forEach(function(opt) {
  $("<div>").text(opt).appendTo(document.body);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Note that I changed one of your entries to demonstrate the importance of ensuring they're treated as text, not HTML.

---

About your code:

```
var str = options;
var temp = new Array();
temp = str.split(", ");
```

The call to `new Array()` is completely unnecessary there, because you're overwriting the value of your `temp` variable on the very next line. `split` returns an array, it doesn't fill in one that it magically reaches out and grabs from the left-hand side of the assignment. :-) (There's also no reason to do `var str = options;` Just use `options` directly.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <div id="main-div"></div>
 <script type = "text/javascript"> 
     var options ="some texts, another text, some more text";
     options.split(',').forEach(function(item){
          $("#main-div").append("<div>"+item+"</div>");
     });
 </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var str = options;
var temp = str.split(", ").map(function(strOption) {
   return '<div>' + strOption + '</div>';
}).join('');
myHTMLElement.innerHTML = $(temp);
```

Comment: don't you want map instead of forEach? forEach will return undefined